# Regex for URL with back slash in the end

Tags: regex

I want a regex for URL like this --

https://stackoverflow.com/    with allows only backslash in the end

Thanks

Comment: Why? Anyways, use this: `^http://stackoverflow\.com/$`

Comment: Are you sure you mean **back**slash? Your example has none

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^http(s)?://[^\\]+\\$`

This is very, very, very general. So it lets the parts between `http` and the backslash at the end let whatever they want. If you wnat further matching there you have to specify what to match.

Comment: You don’t need to group the single `s`.